# CakePHP 3 time column gets date added

Tags: mysql, date, time, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a number of columns defined in my MySQL database as "time". That is, they have a time, but not a date. When they are read by the CakePHP 3 ORM, they are being converted into Cake\I18n\Time objects (through the Cake\Database\Type\TimeType class), but the result always has both a date and a time in it, with the date set to the current date. For example, if the value is "20:00:00", `debug($record['start_time'])` will generate:

```
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
    'time' => '2015-06-21T20:00:00+0000',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
}
```

And when I echo it in a template (without having used `setToStringFormat`), I get something like `6/21/15 8:00 PM`. Of course, I can use `$this->Time->format` to put it back into a time-only format, but it seems very strange that I would need to do so. Why is Cake ignoring the fact that this is *just* a time, and, more importantly, is there a way to make it stop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Date/Time values are all being casted to the same base structure, that is a `DateTime` or `DateTimeImmutable` object, and so naturally date-only values will have a time value added (`00:00:00`), and time-only values come with a date (the current date).

CakePHP will uses specific subclasses depending on the SQL datatype, that is

- `\Cake\I18n\Time` or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` for `TIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, and `DATETIME`
- `\Cake\I18n\Date` or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` for `DATE`

In earlier CakePHP 3 versions there was only `\Cake\I18n\Time`.

It would be nice if there would be a separate class for time-only types, which would have a proper time-only default output format set, but until something like that is added, you'll have to take care of the output format yourself.

### Format in your views

It is up to you how to display this in your views. You can easily use the `i18nFormat()` method of the `Time` class instance

```php
$record['start_time']->i18nFormat(
    [\IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]
)
```

or the `Time` helper, to show only the time part

```php
$this->Time->i18nFormat(
    $record['start_time'],
    [\IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT]
)
```

Guess it wouldn't hurt if bake would generate similar code according to the type of column, you may want to [**suggest that as an enhancement**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues). As mentioned using additional classes (or maybe options) for time-only columns may be something worth to consider too.

### Use a custom time class

If you'd wanted this behavior everywhere where the string representation of the object is being used, without having to manually invoke the formatter, then you could make use of an extended `\Cake\I18n\Time` or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` class with an overriden `$_toStringFormat` property, so that it formats the date accordingly.

**src/I18n/FrozenTimeOnly.php**

```php
namespace App\I18n;

use Cake\I18n\FrozenTime;

class FrozenTimeOnly extends FrozenTime
{
    protected static $_toStringFormat = [
        \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
        \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT
    ];
}
```

**src/config/bootstrap.php**

```php
use Cake\Database\Type\TimeType;
use App\I18n\FrozenTimeOnly;
TimeType::$dateTimeClass = FrozenTimeOnly::class;

// remove the default `useImmutable()` call, you may however
// want to keep further calls for formatting and stuff
Type::build('time'); 
// ...
```

This should pretty much self-explantory, `time` columns that are being mapped to `TimeType`, will now use `App\I18n\FrozenTimeOnly` instead of the default `Cake\I18n\Time`.

#### `DateTimeType::$dateTimeClass` is deprecated

In order to cope with that, a custom database type will be required, which is rather simple too.

**src/Database/Type/TimeOnlyType.php**

```php
namespace App\Database\Type;

use App\I18n\FrozenTimeOnly;
use Cake\Database\Type\TimeType;

class TimeOnlyType extends TimeType
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->_setClassName(FrozenTimeOnly::class, \DateTimeImmutable::class);
    }
}
```

It should be note that currently this will instantiate a data/time class twice, as the parent constructor will invoke `_setClassName()` too, which is where an instance of the given class will be instantiated.

**src/config/bootstrap.php**

```php
use App\Database\Type\TimeOnlyType;
Type::map('time', TimeOnlyType::class);
```

So what this will do, is override the default `time` type mapping to use the custom `\App\Database\Type\TimeOnlyType` class, which in turn will use the `\App\I18n\TimeOnly` class when converting database values to PHP objects, which when converted to a string, will use the time-only format.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Time > Setting the Default Locale and Format String](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Comment: Copy-and-pasted this in and it worked perfectly first time! (Well, once I got my files named correctly...)

Answer (score 0):

the fact is cakePHP perform your time value as Time Object which extends carbon and dateTime so u get a full dateTime instance included date :(

however u can easily perform an automatic set with your entity. U only have to use Accessors & Mutators describe here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators