# CakePHP 3: Hidden DateTime input field is not accepting date

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a datetime field in my database called `start_time` that I would like updated with the current datetime when a user performs a specific action. I would also like this field to be hidden in the edit view.

I have tried a number of combinations in the form in my edit view as well as reading through some other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime) on this but its not working (or i am not fully understanding other posts).

Just some samples of combinations I have tried include:

```php
echo $this->Form->hidden('start_time', ['value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

```php
echo $this->Form->input('start_time', ['type'=>'hidden','value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

If I leave the baked form view of `echo $this->Form->input('start_time')` I see that individual [year], [month], [day] select options are created in the HTML, just wanting to understand if I need to add 6 hidden form options to cover start_time[year], start_time[month], etc... to cover all the Y-m-d H:i:s fields of a MYSQL datetime format...

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks! mk

Comment: "_not accepting_" is not a very precise problem description. What exactly is happening? The same thing as in the linked question, ie after creating/patching the entity, the value ends up as `null`?

Comment: sorry, the data is being saved as `NULL` so yes, the same thing happening in the linked question. I have tried adding the following to my view

`use Cake\I18n\Time;
$now =new Time(date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $this->Form->input('start_time', ['type'=>'hidden','value' => $now]);`

as well as adding the beforeMarshal function detailed in that post, but still it saves as NULL.

Comment: I got it to work as I needed it, thank you for help and other post.
`use Cake\I18n\Time;
Time::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$now = Time::now();
echo $this->Form->input('start_time', ['type'=>'hidden','value' => $now]);`

Comment: Formatting using `Time` should theoretically work in case it's the same problem as in the linked question, as it would use the same format as the parser in the marshalling stage.

Comment: Normally it shouldn't be neccessary to use `setToStringFormat` in this case, in theory passing `Time::now()` as the value should already do it.

Comment: Thanks, meant to add that my solution also included the `beforeMarshal` call you detailed in the other post. Without the `setToStringFormat`, the `Time::now()` value is coming back as yyyy/mm/dd as I assume that is the default format (did not update default in bootstrap.php.)

Comment: What is your database field type ? Is it datetime ?

Comment: yes, DB field is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my issue was actually in the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime). Basically adding the beforeMarshal call into my [mymodel]Table.php and once I did this correctly the valid datetime format was added into my DB field.

Apologies for somewhat duplicate question.