# Integrity Constrains Violation issue : Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, csv, cakephp-3.0

I just want to import csv file data to the database table. All fields were inserted successfully except my custom field that is date field(added_date).

It is display the error that.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'added_date' cannot be null
```

And below is my code for insertion csv data.

```
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $rs[$cnt]['client_id'] = $emapData[0];
    $rs[$cnt]['name'] = $emapData[1];
    $rs[$cnt]['address1'] = $emapData[3];
    $rs[$cnt]['address2'] = $emapData[4];
    $rs[$cnt]['county'] = $emapData[8];
    $rs[$cnt]['city'] = $emapData[6];
    $rs[$cnt]['country'] = $emapData[8];
    $rs[$cnt]['postcode'] = $emapData[7];
    $rs[$cnt]['email_label'] = $emapData[14];
    $rs[$cnt]['time_spent_on_site'] = $emapData[20];
    $rs[$cnt]['added_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); <== gives error that integrity constrains violation.

    $cnt++;
}

fclose($file);

if (count($rs) > 0)
{
    $customers = TableRegistry::get('Customers');
    $entities = $customers->newEntities($rs);

    $customers->connection()->transactional(function () use ($customers, $entities) {
        foreach ($entities as $entity)
        {
            $customers->save($entity);
        }
    });
}
```

And database table structure is as follows:

[image]

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Its concept introduce in Cakephp 3.x that we need to use

`$rs[$cnt]['added_date'] = new \DateTime('now');`

in place of

`$rs[$cnt]['added_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Deprecated in Cakephp 3.x`

Thank you so much for your approach.

Comment: It will both work fine as long as you are using a format that is parsable according to rules defined for the parser. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime/33741772#33741772**