# CakePHP wrong date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I had a field called issue_date in a table that was datetime type in MySQL and I changed to date.

When I am trying to save the date to the database is saving it with
weird years(for example 2196), when the real date is 2003, I made an output of the object before saving it and is showing the real date (2003-06-30)

The field is `issue_date`.

This is my function to save:

```
public function populate(){
        $this->tangoModel=$this->loadModel('Tango');
        $tango=$this->tangoModel->getInvoices();
        $this->obrasModel=$this->loadModel('Obras');
        $obras=$this->obrasModel->getObras();
        foreach($tango as $invoice){
        $data[] = ([
        'issue_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice['issue_date'])),
            'type' => $invoice['type']
        ]
        );
        }
        print_r($data);
        $invoices = $this->Invoices->newEntities($data);
        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
        if ($this->Invoices->save($invoice)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The invoice has been saved.'));
        };
        }


    }
```

This is the output of one object of data array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [issue_date] => 2003-06-30,
        [type] => CRE
    )
```

And this is the output of how is inserted in MySQL

```
    [{"id":"1",
    "issue_date":"2196-11-06",
    "type":"CRE"
    }]
```

This is how the field is validated in the InvoicesTable file in `/Model/Table`:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->add('issue_date', 'valid', ['rule' => 'date'])
            ->allowEmpty('issue_date');
         $validator
            ->allowEmpty('type');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

This is the entity file Invoice.php in `/Model/Entity`

```
   /**
 * Invoice Entity.
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $issue_date
 * @property string $type
 */
class Invoice extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: After changing the column from type `datetime` to `date` did you clear the CakePHP cache? This is the first thing to check when you get weird errors after making changes to the database structure.

Comment: Yes, i have deleted everything that was inside of /tmp/cache

Comment: how it is '2196-11-06' your mysql output. and you say the field is datetime?

Comment: Now the field is Date, originaly, when i use CakePHP to bake the table it was DateTime

Comment: What is `intl.default_locale` set to? Have you used `DateTimeType::setLocaleFormat()` or `Time::setToStringFormat()`? This may be of interest: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime/33741772#33741772**

Comment: The intl.default_locale is set to US: ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en_US'); Its not DateTimeType should be DateType. I tried changing the output to different formats ( 'issue_date' => date('m-d-Y', strtotime($invoice['issue_date'])) and ( 'issue_date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($invoice['issue_date'])) but in this cases nothing was inserted into MySQL

Comment: Right, my comment should have said `DateType::setLocaleFormat()`. Given the locale of `en_US`, the behavior is unexpected (I would have expected the parsing to fail completely), but pretty much the same as in the linked answer, the date will be parsed according the defaults, which is `\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT` (`M/d/yy`), defined in `Time::$wordFormat`. So changing the locale format (for `date` instead of `datetime`) as in the linked answer should be a possible fix for your problem.

Comment: I am trying to what you suggest using: use Cake\Database\Type;
DateType::setLocaleFormat();  but is showing me an error saying: <code>Error: Class 'App\Controller\DateType' not found

Comment: `DateType::setLocaleFormat()` was just for reference, it's not ment to be called like that, you'll have to invoked the method on an instance of that class. In this special case however you should use `Type::build('date')` (the `use` statement is correct), similar to as shown in the linked answer, that way you are using the same instance as the CakePHP core, which is necessary for things to work.

Comment: I have tried use Cake\Database\Type; 
Type::build('date'); now is not showing any error but i am having the same problem(year 2196), Do i understand correct about the code i should use(Type::build('date'))? Thank you very much

Comment: `Type::build('date')->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');` or disable locale parsing, or parse the date manually in beforehand (`Time::parseDate($value, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`) as in the linked answer.

Comment: It worked with Type::build('date')->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked adding in the controller:

```
use Cake\Database\Type; 
Type::build('date')->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Thanks to ndm

Comment: I'd advise to not do that in the controller (but in the bootstrap instead), unless it should really only be applied in that specific controller!