# In mysql date field saving wrong year

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, cakephp-3.0

I'm using MySQL to store my data using PHP. In my table, I have two fields as date (Start_date and End_date). I'm having issue on those fields while saving the data. I gave the input as following
    start_date: 2016-12-03 it saved as ---> 2192-12-03

I don't now what is the issue please anyone help in that.

sample code for inserting in cake php 3

```
 $add_val= $this->school->newEntity(); 
 $save_val= $this->school->patchEntity($add_val, $this->request->data); 
 if ($save = $this->school->save( $save_val)) 
 {
 $passmessage = ['status' => 'success]; 
 }
```

school is the table name.

Comment: what is data type...may you share "show create table your_table;" output

Comment: Zafar Malik@data type is "date"

Comment: some actual PHP code (where you are doing INSERT) and table structure will be more than helpful.

Comment: @mitkosoft actually it is cake php code i got the request and save tham as use well i have no additional code for added for date converation.
table structure is datatype:date,null:no,default:none.

Comment: @RaghulRajendran, the problem is somewhere in PHP code and how input is interpreted there before actual INSERT

Comment: @mitkosoft i don't no where is the issue but i'm using this code for all INSERT.can i share cake php code

Comment: may you share your insert query-

Comment: Zafar Malik@ $add_val= $this->school->newEntity();

                            $save_val= $this->school->patchEntity($add_val, $this->request->data);

                            if ($save = $this->school->save( $save_val)) {

                                $passmessage = ['status' => 'success];

                            }
school is the table name.

Comment: Zafar Malik@ I also added the code in summary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP wrong date in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270890/cakephp-wrong-date-in-mysql)

Comment: Also check **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime/33741772#33741772**