# DateTime not save properly in cakephp 3.x with bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, cakephp

i am using cakephp 3.x, i have one form in which one field is of date. in backend i am using mysql.

my field structure in mysql is `dob` of type `date`.

now in cakephp 3.x i had use below syntax to create input.

```
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array(
    'label' => (__('Date of Birth')),
    'type' => 'text',
    'required' => false,
    'class' => 'form-control date'
));
```

and i had used bootstrap datetimepicker like,

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
});
```

now when i submit the form at and i `print_r` the request data at that time i got this field like this

```
[
....
'dob' => '2016-02-11',
....
]
```

but when i save the record and look in database then it show me random date like `2036-10-25`

can anyone help me please?

Comment: What locale have you set for your application?

Comment: i haven't set it.
i using default one.

Comment: So it's `en_US` then. In that case this seems to be a duplicate of **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime**. You should be able to apply similar to `date` instead of `datetime`, respectively to `\Cake\I18n\Date` instead of `\Cake\I18n\Time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and this is the Final General Solution,

```
//File : src/Model/Table/PatientsTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use ArrayObject;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

class PatientsTable extends Table
{
    ...
    ...
    public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if (isset($data['dob'])) {
            $data['dob'] = Time::parseDate($data['dob'], 'Y-M-d');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared dob type as date but tried to save date in string format instead of date time format. Try this

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;

$this->request->data['dob']= Time::parseDate($this->request->data['dob'],'Y-M-d');
```

Comment: thanks, it's works. but i need global solution that can be put in entity or somewhere else.