# cakephp 3 date input and database issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, datepicker, cakephp-3.2

I'm trying to save a date of birth field in the create user view of my app, I'm using bootstrap datepicker to make it more friendly. have it formatted to yyyy-mm-dd to match the sql date format.

in the create view, when i pick the date it looks like this:
[image: 1993-07-06]

but when I save and go to the database to check the newly created user I always get this on the birthday field:

[image: 2180-01-05]

Does the boostrap datepicker has something to do with it?

i just have this in my js

```
$('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime/33741772#33741772**

Answer (score -1):

birthday field in your database check data type is date after that use save birthday field check date format  please see the below example

```
$date='2016-04-02';
$date1=date('Y-m-d',strtottime($date));
echo $date1;
```

After that save your data into field you. use cake php

```
$this->request->data['Modelname']['datefiled']=$date1;
 $this->Modelname->create();
        if ($this->Modelname->save($this->request->data)) {
}
```

Comment: The question is about CakePHP 3.x

Comment: Fix Typo: $date1=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));