# Use localized date format with date picker in cakephp 3

Tags: date, cakephp, datepicker, locale, cakephp-3.0

I'm building a cakephp 3 app (cakephp v3.3.2 that is) and I have a problem getting dates displayed in the chosen locale (de_DE).

The database field in my example is `invoice_date`, which is of type DATE (stored in a mysql DB).

I want to use a date picker in the web page ("zebra_datepicker"), so in the view I use a single text entry field for the date instead of the three drop-downs that are displayed by default:

```
echo $this->Form->input('invoice_date', [ 'type' => 'text' ]);
```

To get the date displayed in the German format `dd.mm.YY` I changed the global locale setting to

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'de_DE');
```

in `config/bootstrap.php`.

For testing, I created a new record in the database and set the invoice_date to `2016-09-02` (Y-M-D).

If I call the `edit` action of my controller now, I get a default value of `02.09.16` in the form, which is correct.  But if I submit the form back, the database value of the field is changed into `2002-09-16`!

Do I need some extra code in the controller to change the date format back into its original form?  Is this a bug in the localization code of cakephp or did I miss something?  Note, that my controller just uses `patchEntity` to process the posted data.

I already tried adding `date('invoice_date', 'dmy')` in the validationDefault method of the table object, but this didn't change anything:

```
    $validator
        ->date('invoice_date', 'dmy')
        ->requirePresence('invoice_date', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('invoice_date');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33741772/1127933

Comment: @Salines, thank's for the quick response!  The database field I use is of type `DATE`, so specifying d.m.Y should be OK.  Why is the locale setting not used for date parsing in my case?!

Comment: When accepting localized data from the request, it is nice to accept datetime information in a user’s localized format. In a controller, or Dispatcher Filters you can configure the Date, Time, and DateTime types to parse localized formats: Try ```Type::build('date')->setLocaleFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');.```   http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data

Comment: @WileE.Genius When asking such questions you'll have to show your date/time type configuration (from your bootstrap), and mention your exact CakePHP version. There have been quite a few time related changes since the 3.0.0 release.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I just rewrote my question to clarify the facts.  Hope that the problem is clearer now... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem: in bootstrap.php, I had to add:

```
Type::build('date')->useLocaleParser();
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser();
```

With that, I can enter dates like `31.12.16` (d.m.y) and the date gets correctly saved in the database.  This works with the simple validator:

```
$validator
        ->date('invoice_date')
        ->notEmpty('invoice_date');
```

To also support dates like `31.12.2016` (d.m.Y), I had to add an extra parameter to the date validator, like this:

```
$validator
        ->date('invoice_date', 'dmy')
        ->notEmpty('invoice_date');
```