# Date being set to 1970-MM-DD

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, date, cakephp

I have the following field (created by CakePHP 3's `HtmlHelper::input` method) that looks as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepicker boardroombookingdate" required="required" id="date">
```

This field is being set up as a bootstrap datepicker with the following javascript code:

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
    dayViewHeaderFormat : 'MMMM YYYY',
    format : 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    minDate : new Date()
});
```

When I submit the form and debug `$this->request->data` I get this:

```
\src\Controller\BoardroomBookingsController.php (line 48)
[
    'employee_id' => '182',
    'name' => 'sdgsdfg',
    'boardroom_id' => '9',
    'date' => '2016-11-07',
    'start_time' => '07:00',
    'end_time' => '07:00',
    'client_type' => 'internal',
    'clients' => '',
    'notes' => 'a'
]
```

The date here is the correct date that was selected with the datepicker.

However, when I run the following:

```
$boardroomBooking = $this->BoardroomBookings->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $boardroomBooking = $this->BoardroomBookings->patchEntity($boardroomBooking, $this->request->data);
}
```

And run `debug($boardroomBooking)`, I get the following:

```
// Focusing on the date input here as that is where the issue lies
\src\Controller\BoardroomBookingsController.php (line 50)
object(App\Model\Entity\BoardroomBooking) {
    'date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {
        'time' => '1970-11-07T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false
    }
}
```

For some reason the year changes to 1970. This only happens on my live environment and not on my localhost. Any reason why this would be happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: 1970 is the year 0 in "unix time". It might be that the year variable is getting set to 0 somewhere along the path to the server...  More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: You are most probably using locale aware parsing!? **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/cakephp-3-not-saving-datetime**

Comment: This is exactly what happened. Thanks @ndm. Going to mark this as a duplicate, so that people get directed to the correct problem/solution