# CakePHP date parsing in patchEntity

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can't figure out why CakePHP incorrectly parsing my date.

```
    $d = new \Cake\I18n\Date('1920-01-20');
    debug($d);
```

it's ok if used in code

```
object(Cake\I18n\Date) {
    'time' => '1920-01-20T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
}
```

but when it comes from form (i'm using just text input, not Cake's date dropdowns) to patchEntity some magic lurking around (or my blindness)

```
    $member = $this->Members->newEntity();
    $member->profiles = [$this->Members->Profiles->newEntity()];
    $this->Members->patchEntity($member, [
        'username' => 'usern',
        'profiles' => [[
            'birthdate' => '1920-01-20',
            'sex' => 'female']]
    ]);
    debug($member);
```

it's driving me crazy

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Member) {

  'profiles' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Profile) {

      'birthdate' => object(Cake\I18n\Date) {

        'time' => '2179-12-01T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

      },
      'sex' => 'female',
      '[new]' => true,
      '[accessible]' => [
        'member_id' => true,
        'sex' => true,
        'birthdate' => true,
      ],
      '[dirty]' => [
        'birthdate' => true,
        'sex' => true
      ],
      '[original]' => [],
      '[virtual]' => [],
      '[errors]' => [],
      '[invalid]' => [],
      '[repository]' => 'Profiles'

    }
  ],
  'username' => 'usern',
  '[new]' => true,
  '[accessible]' => [
    'username' => true,
    'profiles' => true
  ],
  '[dirty]' => [
    'profiles' => true,
    'username' => true
  ],
  '[original]' => [
    'profiles' => [
      (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Profile) {

        '[new]' => true,
        '[accessible]' => [
          'member_id' => true,
          'sex' => true,
          'birthdate' => true,
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Profiles'

      }
    ]
  ],
  '[virtual]' => [],
  '[errors]' => [],
  '[invalid]' => [],
  '[repository]' => 'Members'

}
```

Why on Earth it become `2179-12-01`? I belive I'm missing something simple, but I stuck with it for hours already.

Comment: Maybe **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/why-are-date-time-values-interpreted-incorrectly-when-patching-saving**, it's old, but still applies.

Comment: @ndm thanks. It works. Sad but i can't find your complete manual earlier.