# How can I modify the default datepicker in CakePHP 3.6?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, datepicker

I am using the default datepicker like this :

```
echo $this->Form->control(
    'created',
    [
        'label' => __('Start date'),
        'type' => 'date',
        'id' => 'datetimepicker',
        'default' => date('d-m-Y') #Set time for today
    ]
);
```

But its kinda ugly:

[image]

Is it possible to change it to a proper datepicker with a calendar instead of 3 dropdown fields?

If not is it possible at least to change the order of the fields and the language?

**EDIT**

After comment suggestions I decided to use [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) like this:

```
echo $this->Form->control('created', ['label' => 'Start date']);

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#created" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

But (probably) because `created` id is in the model it is overriding it and shows the same default datepicker, I have to change the id in order to work, but then its value is not saved....

If I set the type to text it displays the jquery calendar but the date saved is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Use third party datepicker plugins

Comment: Sure, use something like Jquery UI, (old school) these days, but I did meet some Jquery UI guys in boston about 6 years ago, I still have some swag sticker too... :-) (so I'm a bit biased)

Comment: use type `text` and integrate any JS datepicker lib

Comment: @Girish as you can see in my edited post I used text type but the value is not saved

Comment: @netdev The form helper is an automatic generating field type, you can change it from pass `type` like `echo $this->Form->input('created', ['label' => 'Start date', 'type' => 'text']);`

Comment: @Girish I did that but its not saving the value correctly. its saved like this `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: yes, you will need to customize in your Model / Controller and cake validations,
before save please set property in entity `$tableEntity->set('created', $this->request->data('created'));`
FYI: data format should `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: @Girish can you elaborate more please? I added this line in `Model/Entity/CustomerServiceType.php` but I receive this error 
>syntax error, unexpected '$tableEntity' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/why-are-date-time-values-interpreted-incorrectly-when-patching-saving**

Comment: @ndm thx that did the trick