# JQuery datepicker doesn't save selected date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, calendar

I have a `Cakephp 3.6` project on localhost and on a server. I am using this datepicker:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->control('created', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Start date']);
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#created" ).datepicker({ "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy"});
  } );
  </script>
```

When runs locally it saves the selected date without any problem. When I use the online version on the server when I select a date and submit the values, it saves today's date and not the selected one.

The files and database are the same between localhost and server, I just uploaded them.

**EDIT** (FULL CODE)

`add.ctp`

```
<div class="customerServiceTypes form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($customerServiceType) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add service to customer') ?></legend>
        <div ng-app=""  ng-init='servicePrices = <?php echo json_encode($servicePrices); ?>;' >
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('customer_id', ['options' => $customers,'label' => 'Customer']);
            echo $this->Form->control('service_type_id', ['options' => $serviceTypes, 'label' => 'Service', 'ng-model'=>'service_type_id']);
            echo $this->Form->control('price', ['label' => 'Price', 'ng-model'=>'servicePrices[service_type_id]']);
            echo $this->Form->control('paid', ['label' => 'Paid', 'type'=>'number']);
            echo $this->Form->control('created', ['type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Date from']);            
            echo $this->Form->control('card', ['label' => 'Card', 'type' => 'checkbox']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Save')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#created" ).datepicker({ "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy"});
  } );
  </script>
```

`CustomerServiceTypesController.php`

```
public function add($customerid = null)
    {
        $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $customerServiceType = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->patchEntity($customerServiceType, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->CustomerServiceTypes->save($customerServiceType)) {

                //debug($this->request->getData("customer_id"),true);
                //if field paid is not null then create a credit transaction
                if(!is_null($this->request->getData("paid")))
                {
                    $customerServiceType_paid = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->newEntity();
                    $customerServiceType_paid->customer_id = $customerid;
                    $customerServiceType_paid->service_type_id = 3; //HARDCODED 
                    $customerServiceType_paid->price = $this->request->getData("paid");
                    $customerServiceType_paid->created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $customerServiceType_paid->card = $this->request->getData("card");
                    if ($this->CustomerServiceTypes->save($customerServiceType_paid)) {
                        $this->Flash->success(__('Success'));
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->Flash->error(__('Fail'));
                    }
                }

                $this->Flash->success(__('Success'));

                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'edit', $customerid]);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Fail'));
        }
        $customers = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->Customers->find('list', ['limit' => 200])->where(['Customers.id =' => $customerid]);
        $serviceTypes = $this->CustomerServiceTypes->ServiceTypes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $servicePrices = $this->CustomerServiceTypes
            ->ServiceTypes
            ->find()
            ->limit(200)
            ->combine('id','price');

        $this->set(compact('customerServiceType', 'customers', 'serviceTypes','servicePrices'));
    }
```

Comment: Where is the PHP script that actually saves the information? Your JavaScript does n't appear to have a problem, but I'll bet the query does.

Comment: Can you show as the html code (the form)?

Comment: Possibly **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734683/why-are-date-time-values-interpreted-incorrectly-when-patching-saving**, in any case good to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

**Request data for a start date**

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$user=$this->User->get($id);

 $startDate = str_replace('/', '-', $this->request->data['start_date']);

 $user->start_date $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$this->User->save($user);
```