# Cakephp3 format record from REST API

Tags: mysql, json, cakephp-3.0

I am using the rest api and I have a **time** field in the database, it looks like this:

```
08:15:00
```

When I fetch my results I get this:

```
"start": "2017-01-29T08:15:00",
```

How can I format this record so my json result shows just the time?

Comment: simply add the format function in variable like     $time = time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960843/cakephp-3-time-column-gets-date-added/30965562#30965562** but instead of `$_toStringFormat` (or additionally to), you'd need to change `$_jsonEncodeFormat`.

Comment: Where exactly would I add the $time variable? In the model?