# Cakephp 3.7 Need mysql Time to be formatted but not the datetime

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In the application, I have 3 fields in table

```
created(DateTime)
offer_start_time(time) 
offer_start_date(date)
```

having value respectively

```
2019-10-06 06:01:21, 
00:15:00, 
2019-10-06
```

When I fetch record from the database, I get below values

```
[created] => 06:01:21 
[offer_start_time] => 00:15:00
[offer_start_date] => 2019-10-06
```

So in above created value is missing date only showing time.

Below is the Bootstrap configuration for above code

> \Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
>   \Cake\I18n\Date::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); 
>   \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('HH:mm:ss'); 
>   \Cake\I18n\Time::setJsonEncodeFormat('HH:mm:ss');
>   Type::build('time')->useImmutable();
>   Type::build('date')->useImmutable();
>   Type::build('datetime')->useImmutable();
>   Type::build('timestamp')->useImmutable();

This issue is applicable for all Datetime columns in the tables, if I change

> \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('HH:mm:ss');

to

> \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::setJsonEncodeFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');

then time colomns start displaying date, Please let me know how to fix this

Comment: You'd either need to format manually, or use a custom type for your `TIME` columns, so that you don't have to modify `Time/FrozenTime` which is used for `DATETIME` columns, see **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960843/cakephp-3-time-column-gets-date-added/30965562** and **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/13440**.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example :

```
created(DateTime)//use this  $created= date('Y-m-d H:m:s'); /// [created] => 2019-10-06 06:01:21
offer_start_time(time)//use this $offer_start_time = date(H:m:s'); /// [offer_start_time ] => 06:01:21
offer_start_date(date)//use this $offer_start_date = date('Y-m-d'); /// [offer_start_date] => 2019-10-06
```

Comment: This needs to be done in every piece of code where the above values are used, I need solution by which Cakephp returns expected values. So that no change in Controller/Views needs to be done.